# Extracting long text from database and image url from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display description and image(display the image directory (example.com/upload/pic.jpg) which is in my database in an email but seems not to work although other fields are showing up in the mail. Here is my code.

Comment: what is the value of `$captain_image = $row["imagesPath"];`? I'm guessing a local path instead of a full server URL. You also need to send it out as HTML.

Comment: *(display the image directory (example.com/upload/pic.jpg)* - if that is the actual value, it's wrong. It needs to read as `http://example.com/upload/pic.jpg` or with the added www such as `http://www.example.com/upload/pic.jpg` on top of what I said about sending as html.

Comment: @Fred-ii- in the database, it is just  images/pic.jpg. Send as HTML, could you be more clear on that please?

Comment: `http://www.example.com/images/pic.jpg` is what it should read as. You also need to add to that row's address value. and add an `img src`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Okay. I will try that

Comment: I posted an answer below to better illustrate.

Comment: @Fred-ii-. Thanks a lot Fred.. Everything is working now. best!

Comment: You're welcome. I take it you saw the answer I wrote up for you below? I made a few edits to it also.

Comment: and marking the question as solved, otherwise others may be tempted to post more answers.

Comment: Sure , i have just marked it.. Thanks once again, Fred

Comment: You're most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in comments, the image requires a full URL for it and not your local machine's path, plus an `img src` is required and to send as HTML.

I.e.:

`<img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">`

Then to send as HTML, visit the PHP.net website:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

It contains examples, but I will post one here and pulled from the manual on the `mail()` function:

```
<?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

You can basically add the extra `http://www.example.com/` to your existing variable for the image. Don't forget the trailing slash at the end.

I.e.:

```
$captain_image = "http://www.example.com/". $row["imagesPath"];
```

and use the `$captain_image` variable for the `img src` code in your mailout.

I.e.:

`<img src="$captain_image">` in double quotes.

However, and for your code, it would read as, and escaping the double quotes for `$captain_image` inside the variable declaration with `\`. (This is important in order to have proper HTML markup and not cause a parse error at the same time):

```
$message_coordinator .= "Image: <img src=\"$captain_image\"><br>";
```

Use `<br>` for line breaks when sending as HTML.

- Sidenote: Variables do not get parsed in single quotes, so `<img src='$captain_image'>` will fail and will only show the variable name rather than the image.

Consider using PHPMailer, it will make your life a lot easier.

- https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Or Swiftmailer:

- http://swiftmailer.org/